# I want to display genres of a movie

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
function showMovies (dataMovie) {
    const main = document.getElementById('main');
    main.innerHTML = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < dataMovie.length; i++) {
        const newMovie = document.createElement('div');
        newMovie.innerHTML = 
        `<div class="movie-img">
             <img src="${url_poster + dataMovie[i].poster_path}" alt="${dataMovie[i].title}-poster">
        </div>
        <div class="movie-info">
            <h3>${dataMovie[i].title}</h3>
            <div class="genres">
            </div>
            <p>${dataMovie[i].release_date}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="movie-overview">
            <h3>Synopsis:</h3><br>
            <p>${dataMovie[i].overview}</p>
        </div>`

    main.appendChild(newMovie);

    for (let j = 0; j < genresList.length; j++) {
        dataMovie[i].genre_ids.forEach(id => {
            if (genresList[j].id === id) {
                let g = '';
                const div = document.querySelector('.genres');
                const p = document.createElement('p');
                g += genresList[j].name;
                p.innerHTML = `<p>- ${g} </p>`
                div.appendChild(p);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I want to display all genres of one movie.
When i get one movie i've got no problem, when i get more than one, the first takes all the genres and no genres are displayed for the others.
movieData is my data.results of the api (tmdb).

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting the same `.genres` all the time.
Try this please:

```
const div = newMovie.querySelector('.genres');
```

```js
function showMovies(dataMovie) {
  const main = document.getElementById('main');
  main.innerHTML = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < dataMovie.length; i++) {
    const newMovie = document.createElement('div');
    newMovie.innerHTML =
      `<div class="movie-img">
             <img src="{url_poster + dataMovie[i].poster_path}" alt="{dataMovie[i].title}-poster">
        </div>
        <div class="movie-info">
            <h3>{dataMovie[i].title}</h3>
            <div class="genres">
            </div>
            <p>{dataMovie[i].release_date}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="movie-overview">
            <h3>Synopsis:</h3><br>
            <p>{dataMovie[i].overview}</p>
        </div>`

    main.appendChild(newMovie);

    for (let j = 0; j < genresList.length; j++) {
      dataMovie[i].genre_ids.forEach(id => {
        if (genresList[j] === id) {
          let g = '';
          const div = newMovie.querySelector('.genres');
          const p = document.createElement('p');
          g += genresList[j].name;
          p.innerHTML = `<p>- ${g} </p>`
          div.appendChild(p);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}

var genresList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
showMovies([{genre_ids:[1,2,3]},{genre_ids:[4,5,6]}])
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you write `const div = document.querySelector('.genres');` you are always selecting the **first element on the page that matches the selector**.

One idea would be to add an id to the movie container, which you can then use on your query.
For instance something like this:

1. when you create the container div:

```js
const newMovie = document.createElement('div');
newMovie.classList.add('new-movie');
newMovie.setAttribute('movie-id', dataMovie[i].id);
```

2. then on your selector:

```js
const div = document.querySelector(`.new-movie[movie-id="${dataMovie[i].id}"] .genres`);
```

This would give you the `.genres` div inside the correct container (instead of the first one on the page).

For a different approach you could also try to use

```js
const div = newMovie.querySelector('.genres');
```

instead of

```js
const div = document.querySelector('.genres');
```

Which should give you the same result